# Is it possible to add Spring Retry information (counters for number of attempts, successes, failures, timeouts) to Actuator?

Tags: spring, spring-retry

I am using the spring-retry dependency and I need to add Spring Retry information (counters for number of attempts, successes, failures, timeouts) to Spring Actuator is this possible? There is also a RetryStatistics class, perhaps it can be based on it?

Comment: You could implement a `RetryStatistics` which uses Micrometer (assuming you are on Spring Boot 3+) which would then be used for metrics.

Comment: Could you help a little with the details

Comment: create a class that implements that interface and delegates to Micrometer metrics.